# Getting dates in R

Tags: r

[image: 1]

shows a link to what I have been trying to code in R to get proper dates to work with in R studio.

[image: 2]

shows the file I have downloaded to R.

I am trying to get some proper dates to work with in R. I can only work with the year and the month. For example, row 1 gives me the number 192607. I would like to change the format to 1926(year)-07(month).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't add data/code as screenshots. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 1):

Do you want this?

```
gsub("(.*)(\\d{2})","\\1-\\2",d)
```

or

```
gsub("(\\d{2}$)","-\\1",d)
```

such that

```
[1] "1926-07"
```

**Data**

```
d <- 192607
```

---

Within a data frame, you can try

```
transform(
  df,
  Date = gsub("(\\d{2}$)","-\\1",Date)
)
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. The excel sheet is a screenshot of the first observations/dates. There is over 1000 rows with dates from 1926 until 2020, so I need a code that can change all of the thousand dates. Do you know how to do this? Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

Does this give desired output:

```
> df <- data.frame(Date = c(192607:192612),
+                  L10 = c(-.12, 1.13, 0.59, -4.29, -3.28, -2.49))
> 
> df
    Date   L10
1 192607 -0.12
2 192608  1.13
3 192609  0.59
4 192610 -4.29
5 192611 -3.28
6 192612 -2.49
> paste0(gsub('^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1-\\2', df$Date), '-01')
[1] "1926-07-01" "1926-08-01" "1926-09-01" "1926-10-01" "1926-11-01" "1926-12-01"
> as.Date(paste0(gsub('^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1-\\2', df$Date), '-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d')
[1] "1926-07-01" "1926-08-01" "1926-09-01" "1926-10-01" "1926-11-01" "1926-12-01"
> format(as.Date(paste0(gsub('^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1-\\2', df$Date), '-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m')
[1] "1926-07" "1926-08" "1926-09" "1926-10" "1926-11" "1926-12"
>
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. The excel sheet is a screenshot of the first observations/dates. There is over 1000 rows with dates from 1926 until 2020, so I need a code that can change all of the thousand dates. Do you know how to do this? Kind regards

Comment: You can save it in same column or in a different column using below code: df$Date_Formatted <- format(as.Date(paste0(gsub('^([0-9]{4})([0-9]{2})$', '\\1-\\2', df$Date), '-01'), format = '%Y-%m-%d'), '%Y-%m'). If you wish to save in same column just use df$Date in place of df$Date_Formatted in above code.